# Qt Deploy to Remote Linux Host - How do I specify files to deploy?

Tags: qt

I have created a new Qt project from the QtGui tempate, and I want to deploy it to a remote device. How do I specify that I want the executable to be deployed? In the run settings, I just get told "Don't know what to run."

Is there something I need to specify in my pro file?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Fixed it with this in my pro file:

```
target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
INSTALLS += target
```